# Where to find notes.exe from within an RCP plug-in

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, lotus-notes

I currently have an `RCP Eclipse` plug-in that goes into `IBM Lotus Notes`. I need to call the `notes.exe` binary with some arguments (kind of like from a .bat file), and I know how to do that when I know *WHERE* Notes is installed.

**How do I find out where `IBM Lotus Notes` is installed, so I can know where to call the `notes.exe` from?**

NOTE: Please don't suggest I look in the typical install folder, I'd like to be able to do it regardless of whether it's the typical default folder or not. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Platform.getInstallLocation() points to the [Notes_install]/framework/rcp/eclipse folder

Just remove the suffix and you have the Notes install

Answer (score 1):

Look in the Windows registry under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Notes\shell\open\Command

See [answers to this old StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62289/read-write-to-windows-registry-using-java) for Java code that can read/write the registry.

Comment: I also found 'Platform.getInstallLocation()' which points to the framework/rcp/eclipse subfolder of the Notes install, and clear sailing from there on. Would there be any disadvantage in using this seemingly simpler solution?

Comment: No disadvantage that I can think of.